# EMI standards just for power on/off

Tags: motor, inductor, emc, flyback, fcc

I know the FCC has EMI/EMC maximums for connected emissions into the AC power cable while electronics are on.

But, are there FCC requirements on the brief connected emissions/bursts when the electronics are manually switched on or off?

I have a 120V AC fan (maybe built in 2005) which, when switched off, disrupts my digital cable TV reception (due to the usual [flyback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode) problem, but there is no circuitry added here to suppress flyback).  I wonder if the FCC would still allow this.  Most of my other fans have no such problem.

Comment: The requirement would be in your device getting disturbed, not the switch on the fan, (or if there has been any recent change, possibly both). Transient TV disturbance not casing the device to restart or crash would fall into category B, no user interaction required and normal operation commence when disturbance is removed. How mush does it disturb you? Enough to crack open the fan and solder in countermeasures?

Comment: I don't think there is any test that would cause the fan to fail radiated or conducted emissions. But there is a fast transient immunity test that requires your TV and related devices to function correctly when a specific noise waveform is injected into the AC power supply. I think it is called the "fast transient" test. If the problem is due to radiated transients that occur only at power-on and power-off, I don't think there is any test for that. Note that I am not an expert in this area, so this is just a comment.

Comment: Though you didnt ask this, once could abate the problem by installing a series RC "snubber" across the switch.  Would also help prolong the life of the switch. But the product would need room inside for the capacitor to fit; it needs to be AC "line rated" capacitor, which are bulky.

Answer (score 0):

The usual EMC standards are mainly concerned with frequent to continuous sources of interference.  All operating modes of the EUT must be evaluated, but a fan only has two (on and off), and in fact it's the transition between the two that creates the noise in this case.  But more than that, the fan wouldn't be subject to these standards anyway as its operating frequency is quite low and it doesn't contain an internal clock or anything.

If the fan motor were brushed type, I'm not sure offhand which way that would go: the above reasoning still applies, but this type is notorious for producing brush arcing noise, and often requires filtering when in equipment that's subject to EMC testing for other reasons (i.e. because it's electronic).  I've not looked up an FCC cert for, say, a shopvac before, but if they exist, that would be an answer.

I'm not familiar with more strict or involved standards; perhaps there are MIL STDs concerned with not just operating states but the transitions between them as well, and those would require such emissions to be controlled.  A SIGINT grade fan could be quite an expensive item, I suppose.  Not at all because of the solution (put an R+C across the switch), but for the certification/approval, and the low production quantity.

I am also aware of circumstances that might apply, regardless of product certification: one action involved a water well pump motor, which was generating significant and sustained emissions, which affected a nearby registered radio operator. Complaints were issued, then cease-and-desist, servicing was performed, the issue was not resolved, a fine was issued.  Kind of tragic I guess; ordinary plumbing service wouldn't know (or have any way) to check or fix EMI anyway.

It's worth knowing the legal basis for such regulations in your region (FCC, so USA we can assume).  While the FCC does occasionally do surveys themselves (the classic, whatever, white van studded with antennas), it's my understanding they don't do this very often these days, and mostly rely on reports -- registered users of spectrum have the right to make complaints, which have actionable consequences.  Typically, action consists of locating the offender, sending a C&D, and resolving or escalating the situation from there, which can include fines (not sure about jail time?).  So, avoid interfering with amateur radio operators, commercial stations, aircraft, etc.

But none of these conditions apply here: you are evidently not a registered user, and you are also the identified offender.  Enough neighbors complaining of a dropped TV station, might be grounds for action, I'm not sure; since that's clearly affecting the commercial station's reception area.  You do have a case of interference, but it's intermittent, and by a device that's already met approvals (whether by testing or exemption).

Mind, IANAL, not legal advice, etc. Let me know in comments if I've misrepresented anything here.

So, all in all, an intermittent noisy switch isn't very problematic to most users of the airwaves, and probably isn't grounds for regulatory action.